# "По истечении", "по завершении" — И или Е на конце?

Tags: орфография, окончания

Как правильно писать: "по истечении", "по завершении"? Какое тут должно быть окончание: И или Е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно говорить "по истечении", "по завершении", однако же "по прилете", "по приезде".
Также "вследствие" (в значении "по причине") пишется через Е.
Пример: *"Вследствие плохой погоды рейс отложили"*.

Answer (score 1):

По истечении, по завершении, по приезде, по окончании. Производные предлоги.